# What happens when you execute "ls" in Bash

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, filesystems

Can some one provide me a detailed description of what happens when you execute the "ls" command in linux.  What system calls are used? What does the file system do? Obviously depending on which file system is used.  Is someone can provide an in depth discussion on this topic or point me to some good resources that would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: *"What system calls are used?"* -- Perform the shell command `strace ls`.

Comment: If you want to know muche deeper, on modern x86 you may use `perf` which will show you full trace of the command based on Intel Processor Tracing technology.

Comment: Why not check the source code? 
https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-230/ls/
http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Bash as command interpreter checks whether there such special words in it's own language: shell keywords or shell built-ins.
2. ls isn't among shell keywords, then it checks aliases and replace alias with it's value, most likely there should be something like that: `ls='ls --color=auto'`
3. it looks for ls executable in paths specified by PATH env variable. Usually it's `/bin/ls`
4. It forks (`fork()`) new process and execs it's code (`exec()`). Process env is inherited from parent process to new "ls" process.
5. New process becomes session leader and starts working on foreground (bash is moved to background)
6. ls process loads shared libraries from LD_PATHs (`ldd /bin/ls`)
7. it executes lots of systemcalls, you can check by `strace`, and the main part I believe are `openat()` and `getdents()` first opens directory and second reads entries inside there.
8. prints output and exits, sends `wait()` signal and parent process bash terminates it completely.

Comment: I know this is meant to be a high-level overview, but there are many inaccuracies here. (1,2) It is important to parse the command first, we cannot simply check for every token in the alias mapping (5) More importantly, there's no such thing as a session leader or foreground/background thing involved -- the child process from step4 calls exec*() to run /bin/ls, while the parent process calls wait() on the pid of the child and blocks. When the child exits, the parent continues from the wait() call. (8) is incorrect, the child just exits and the parent continues from wait().

Answer (score 0):

1. current process (we call parent process, or parent) find ls in $PATH variable,eg  /usr/bin/ls
2. parent(process) fork a child( process), and pass all enviroment, child process image is /usr/bin/ls
3. without arguments, so child find env `PWD`, eg /foo/bar and excute (/usr/bin/ls /foo/bar)
4. child process output , exit
5. parent become interactive again